# How do I show a row based on the value of another field in a separate row?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

In the table below, the meta keys `logo_ID` and `show_logo` are associated with each other based on the `post_id` field. How do I get the value of `logo_ID` for rows which have a `show_logo` of  `1` using **only mysql**?

```
post_id  meta_key     meta_value
-------  -----------  ----------
262      logo_ID      263       
262      show_logo    0         
260      logo_ID      261       
260      show_logo    1         
258      logo_ID      259       
258      show_logo    1
```

If it looks familiar it's because this is from the WP `postmeta` table. I'm using `$wpdb` to query the db so everything has to be in mysql (no WP functions anywhere).

Comment: are you using SQL or wordpress functions?

Comment: Sorry, this is just pure MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join the `wp_postmeta` table to itself, specifying the value you want in the `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT pm2.post_id, pm2.meta_key
FROM wp_postmeta pm1 
JOIN wp_postmeta pm2 
    ON pm2.post_id = pm1.post_id AND pm2.meta_key = 'logo_ID'
WHERE pm1.meta_key = 'show_logo' AND pm1.meta_value = 1
```

If you are dealing with a lot of data, this is fairly fast as it will use indexes on the `wp_postmeta` table. You can `JOIN` the `wp_postmeta` more if you want to get other values as criteria as well, or the `wp_posts` table to get the other post fields.

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7fa5e/4)

Answer (score 1):

pivot the rows by using `CASE` statement based on the values of `meta_key` so you can show the values of `post_id` in a row, then wrap it in a subquery.

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT  post_id,
            MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'logo_ID' THEN meta_value ELSE NULL END) logo_ID,
            MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'show_logo' THEN meta_value ELSE NULL END) show_logo
    FROM    tableName
    GROUP BY post_ID
) a
WHERE show_logo = 1
```

- [**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f6dd3/3)

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to just join the table to itself to take advantage of indexes?